# Why Can't I See the Top and Right Corners?

Tags: html, css

Why can't I see the top and right corners of the `div` element in the example below:

```css
.test {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

For some reason the border is only showing up on the top and left sides. Why is it so and how to fix it?

Comment: Because 100% plus x is more than 100%, for any x > 0.

Comment: (And you might need to eliminate the default body margin as well.)

Comment: `body` has a padding. Also, `border-width` isn't included into the 100%.

Comment: @CBroe body margin wont help here as 100% width + 2x 2px border are still more then 100%. `box-sizing: border-box;` will

Comment: `body` has 8px margin. please remove it.

Comment: @SatoTakeru body margin is not the problem here. and it is not necessarily 8px. Most browser UA have it set at 8px which equals then 16px. The added border width causes the overflow.

Comment: @SatoTakeru I set margin: -8px. Now I can see the right and bottom borders but not the top and left sides. :)

Comment: `body: margin: 0;` and `.test: box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: May God bless you, Mister Takeru. Thank you so much.